# "-" used in NUnit's [Category] name

Tags: c#-4.0, nunit

Anyone know why i cant do the following with NUnit?

```
[Test]
[Category(@"Non-Special Test")]
```

i thought @ before hand would solve that issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is [know bug in nUnit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/590717), but you could replace `hyphen-minus ( - )` this with `dash ( — )`

For example:

```
[Category(@"Non—Special Test")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from NUnit 2.5.6, does not allow characters like `-` and `+`. According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/590717) one of the reasons for this is that these characters were not recognized when specifying categories in the NUnit console runner argument list.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that + cheers for the link. Ive marked akim as the selected answer as he was first/less rep points but i have upvoted ur answer as well. Thanks again.